# OST of One Piece episode 803 when Sanji charged at Niji and then kicked him in the face

Tags: one-piece, music

In episode 803 of *One Piece* around 11:14-12:11, there's a song when Sanji charged at Niji and then kicked him in the face.

What is the name of the OST?

Answer (score 1):

### You can listen here: [OnePieceTrackList](http://onepiecetracklist.com/Music/365.mp3)

Starting from 10:58, the track is "Preemptive Strike ~Pump Up Their Hearts' Volume~". Track 17 from the album "Strong World"